# Service Stack FOSS Exception

Tags: servicestack

Recently I began development on a Service Stack open source project.  Yesterday I passed the 10-free operation limit:

```
The free-quota limit on '10 ServiceStack Operations' has been reached. 
Please see https://servicestack.net to upgrade to a commercial license
```

I am working under an assumption that there is an exception for open source projects: [FOSS Exception](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/license.txt#L15)

It may be that my interpretation of this license is incorrect.

In simple terms, how does the FOSS exception work for open source projects that want to use ServiceStack v4 (or other FOSS projects)?  Do I need to purchase a license?  If so, how does this affect the sharing of the source code, and can fellow contributors make use of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I received this answer from Demis Bellot on the Service Stack G+ community.

> The official NuGet packages are covered by the Commercial License,
>   whilst the AGPL/FOSS Exception License covers the source code that's
>   on GitHub and is listed in the root directory of SS repos, e.g:
>   https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/license.txt#L40
>
> All the source code for v4 is on GitHub and Open Source projects can
>   build their own forks and use the test license key at:
>   https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Text.Tests/App.config#L4
>
> The easiest way for OSS projects to get the latest binaries is to
>   build the main ServiceStack.sln in:
>   https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/src
>
> They can then use the pre-compiled dlls for ServiceStack's sub
>   projects at:
>   https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/lib Or if
>   preferred you can build the sub projects and use those compiled
>   binaries instead.

Comment: which means in my open source project on github, i'm not allowed to use the nuget packages with the licence?

Comment: Correct.  The test license key will not work with the NuGet packages.  You can still use the nuget packages in your open source project if your needs don't exceed the [free usage quotas](https://servicestack.net/download#free-quotas).

Comment: why is the nuget comfort removed for oss projects? :(

Comment: Here's how to build DLLs for .NET or local NuGet packages for .NET Core: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35049866/how-do-i-get-servicestack-binaries-for-use-with-the-foss-exception/42642371#42642371